# Is there any benefits of using Interpreter pattern?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

Is there any benefits of using constructs like:

`return "FIRTNAME LASTNAME"
       .replace(/FIRSTNAME/g, person.firstName)
       .replace(/LASTNAME/g, person.lastName)`

comparing to plain simple `return person.firstName + " " + person.lastName`
?

Comment: I'd prefer the more simple approach as it's more familiar to most programmers.  Also, it would avoid spelling mistakes like the one you have there.  Nice name, btw :)

Comment: Alternatively, make a `string.Format();` function.  I have one to hand if that would be of use.

Comment: In ES6, you could use `\`${person.firstName} ${person.lastName}\``

Comment: Your first approach does not work when `person.firstName` accedentally contains `LASTNAME`. Avoid this pattern, and when you really need a templating language then use a proper one (there are many libraries available).

Comment: Know about libs (e.g. `sprintf`) although would like to know if it's kinda good programming style to use `replace` way?